# How to categorise flower species for classification of image

Tags: python

first of all thank you for your attention for my questions. I believe that you do not hesitate to answer my question. My questions are below
1. I have so many various species of flower pictures in only one folder. Flower species are mixed in that folder. In order to run deep learning model it need to be sorted by species. How to sort them with their species into different folder? Doing this manually will take so many times and doing this manually is very hard to me. Please advise.

Comment: it's 70% data preprocessing, 20% ml, 10% wait

Comment: @WehFlower is there any naming convention in your filenames? Something that we can use as a pattern to put files into their respective folders.

Comment: no there is no convention in my filename

Comment: @Weh Flower how did you name each file? can you give us some samples.

Comment: it has random name